# Wordpress redirect incorrectly on ubuntu server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am deploying wordpress on ubuntu server 12.04.3 LTS.

I created a virtual host in my /etc/apache2/ports.conf

NameVirtualHost *:82
Listen 82

In my sites-available, I have a wordpress file as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:82>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/rex/sites/wordpress
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/rex/sites/wordpress>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All 
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In my ~/sites/wordpress/.htaccess, I have the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The problem I'm having is that when I type in my server ip and port number in browser, 192.168.1.61:82, I got redirected to 192.168.1.61, and error message says "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right below the `ServerAdmin` line:

```
ServerName 192.168.1.61
```

Comment: @user2730490 are you sure wordpress isn't responsible for this redirecting?

Comment: I think it's caused by wordpress, because when I just put an empty index.php file in ~/sites/wordpress, it works.

Comment: @user2730490 you probably have to set the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL to `http://192.168.1.61:82/wordpress`

Comment: Where are these two files?

Comment: @user2730490 not files, wordpress settings